# Drag drop between Datagridviews that are added at run time

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Not a programmer but i dabble. So pardon the stupidity.

I have gotten drag drop to work in a previous program where the Datagridviews where preset , the problem im now facing is i have >10 departments all with different qty workstations. I have a form that gets the qty of workstations and the workstation name @ login from a sql table and adds the qty naming them as they are added. Im hoping to be able to drag and drop jobs into the workstations for the guys to work on.

Below is what i have so far but dont even know if its possible or where to start on the drag over or mouse move events because the datagridview names arnt fixed.

```
 Dim WSNames As New DataTable
        '2  Call Current Stored WSSettings Values from SQL DB
        Dim SqlGetWSSettingsData As New SqlCommand("Select  [WorkSpace Name] from PASch_WrkSpcAllocator ", connection)
        Dim SqlDataAdapterSqlGetWSSettingsData As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlGetWSSettingsData)
        Dim DTSqlGetWSSettingsData As New DataTable()
        SqlDataAdapterSqlGetWSSettingsData.Fill(DTSqlGetWSSettingsData)

        DGVCounter = 0
        Do Until DGVCounter = NoOfWorkStations
            Dim dgv As New DataGridView
            Me.Controls.Add(dgv)
            dgv.Width = (Me.Width / NoOfWorkStations) - 20

            dgv.Location = New Point(dgv.Width * (DGVCounter) + 20, 50)
            dgv.Name = DTSqlGetWSSettingsData.Rows(DGVCounter)(0).ToString
            DGVCounter = DGVCounter + 1
            dgv.BackgroundColor = Color.White
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = False
            dgv.ReadOnly = True


         
           
        Loop
```

Comment: Pretty much the same process as if the DGV was added at design time.  Only catch is you will need to add the event handler in code via AddHandler()

Comment: Thanks @Hursey such.ok ,so ive managed to get the handler to work for most of it the only thing to work out is how to retrieve the DGV that received the drop , sender references the form in the dragdrop event and im lost , Any suggestions ? im happy to do the reasearch and learn.

Comment: Have you added the dragdrop  handler to the form or the DGV?  Sender should be the DGV

Comment: This is what ive done ;
As the DGV  is dynamically created i add the handler:
 `AddHandler dgv.DragDrop, AddressOf dgv_DragDrop`

Comment: Then in the function :
`Public Sub dgv_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop

        For Each drr As DataGridViewRow In dgvs.Rows
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = CType(drr.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
            For i As Int32 = 0 To drr.Cells.Count - 1
                row.Cells(i).Value = drr.Cells(i).Value
            Next
            dgvs.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvs.CurrentRow.Index)
            sender.Rows.Insert(0, row)
        Next
    End Sub`

Comment: Away from a pc for a while, but think the issue is Handles Me.DragDrop  on the dgv_DragDrop method.  That will be firing for the form rather than the target dgv